# BootstrapValidator + PHP : edit data in modal from table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrapvalidator

I am a lit a bit lost because I didn't find an example to guide me to solve my problem.

I display some data in a tab (contact) with a button (edit) at each line with PHP code.

When I click the button, I open the modal and display the information from the selected line.

Now I would like to validate the form with bootstrapvalidator but the validation doesn't see my modal because the modal is identified with the id of the contact like this : `id="myModal<?php echo $contact['id'];?>"`.

In my jquery script, I don't know how to identify the modal from this id.

Example with a reset password function modal:

```
<td>
            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalR<?php echo $user['login']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <a id="del" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  onclick="deleteAccount('<?php echo $user['login']; ?>')" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>             

            <!-- Modal Mot de passe -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModalR<?php echo $user['login']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel<?php echo $user['login']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel<?php echo $user['login']; ?>">Login :&nbsp;<?php echo $user['login']; ?></h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="resetPwd" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Mot de passe*</label>
                                    <div class='col-md-8'>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwd1" 
                                            data-bv-identical="true"
                                            data-bv-identical-field="confirmPwd"
                                            data-bv-identical-message="Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirmer le mot de passe*</label>
                                    <div class='col-md-8'>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPwd" id="pwd2"
                                            data-bv-identical="true"
                                            data-bv-identical-field="pwd"
                                            data-bv-identical-message="Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">  
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-11 control-label" style="font-weight:normal" >(*) champs obligatoires</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sortir</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
    $('#resetPwd').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Cette valeur n\'est pas valide',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },fields: {
            pwd: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Champ requis'
                    }
                }
            },confirmPwd: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Champ requis'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('success.form.bv', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#myModalR').modal('hide');
```

Comment: check in view source  are you able to see that unique id

Comment: Hi,Thanks for you answer but what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, i understood what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, i understood what you mean. 
I am inserting the html result of an Ajax call (<body onload="getPrt()">) in a div Inside the body (<div id="viewPrinter">). I have a button EDIT in each line in the table (the result). That's my problem, how can I make validator enabled when opening the edit modal? All my input are completed with the right printer info, I can edit it with a php script if I use "form action=script.php" but not visible if a use bootsrapValidator, it doesn't see my modal. Thanks

Comment: you can see it in pictures : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C96DDCE9BBAB6CE2!1512&authkey=!ALlXK-K2ElJyiCM&ithint=folder%2cjpg

Comment: I don't see the html code included with my Ajax script when I view source code on Firefox or IE. I am frustated.

Comment: when you inspect your html do you see your php value replaced !!!

Comment: I  found the solution. I have moved the modal in the page visible in the DOM. I open it then with jquery. I am glad. Thanks